# log4j1.2 - central appender on top of several appenders

Tags: java, log4j

I'm quite new at Java and log4j, and i have been asked to create a new log on top of those existing. 
The situation is : batchLog takes care of BATCH, wesLog takes cares of WES. Both INFO level. That's easy. My task is to create an errorLog that will gather ERROR from BOTH Logs. And it is getting weird now. Here are the main lines of my code :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, errorLog
log4j.logger.batchLog=INFO, batchLog
log4j.logger.wesLog=INFO, wesLog

log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.wesLog.File=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/logs/ECL_WES.log
log4j.additivity.wesLog=false

log4j.appender.errorLog.File=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/logs/ECL_ERROR.log
log4j.additivity.errorLog=false

log4j.appender.batchLog.File=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/logs/ECL_BATCH.log
log4j.additivity.batchLog=false
```

And I got some issues, with WES writing in wesLog (as intended) but BATCH was writing in batchLog AND wesLog (errorLog working fine). 
I have been tempted by creating each first Logs its own ERROR appender and both writing in the same file, but i heard it is working badly.

Help will greatly appreciated !
Alex

PS : in the main program, they keep referring to the batchLog and wesLog as batchLogger and wesLogger (see the +ger) and it seems to be working fine, and i don't get why, as for me it refers to another, non existing, non described, object. Any idea ?

Comment: To write the same log in a particular logger and also in the root logger, you should set additivity as true.

Comment: i do not have any poblem with writing in several logs, but with the fact that it writes them in too many places. The wesLog receives logs from wesLog AND batchLog even with both additivity being equal to false and the fatc that the 2 of them are not related.